# How to insert data using peewee?

Tags: python, python-2.7, peewee

I have described a model of peewee:

```
class Products(peewee.Model):
    article = peewee.CharField(primary_key=True)
    name = peewee.CharField()
    price = peewee.FloatField()
    price_distributor = peewee.FloatField()
    price_discount = peewee.FloatField()

    class Meta:
        database = get_db_connection()
```

Then tried to insert data like:

```
row = {
                'article': row[0].value,
                'name': row[1].value,
                'price': row[2].value,
                'price_distributor': row[3].value,
                'price_discount': row[4].value
            }

# Insert
Products.insert(row)
```

It does not give any errors, just database is empty

Comment: have you `save()`ed afterwards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call .execute() afterwards. Same for update & delete.

Comment: Do you mean this? `Products.insert(row).execute()`?

Comment: Can you help, how to get field value by name here? `return Products.select().where(Products.article == article).get()`?